# laravel 5.2 lists() method output different on server Issue with DB::lists method

Tags: php, list, laravel, laravel-5

```
return $local_places = DB::table('locals')->distinct('id')->lists('id');
```

**Locally on Windows**
it outputs **[1]** which is fine as should be but 
**Server**
in server running Ubunutu 14.04 it outputs ["1"] which is having double quotes and so my code is not working. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `mysql`.

The problem must be with `mysqlnd` library.
On the ubuntu server try this

```
$sudo dpkg -l | grep mysqlnd
```

If you do't get anything, it means you have missed the extension. You may install it like so

```
$sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

(assuming you have `php5`)

`mysqlnd` is a native driver and it'll give you numbers as numbers and not string.

Comment: because of you people stack overflow is what it should be

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert your output to a number like this:

```
$integer = intval($string);
```

Comment: but I am passing the array to another function can you elaborate where should I put that ?

$places = DB::table('locals')->distinct('id')->lists('id');
$local_places = Place::all()->whereIn('id', $places)->lists('name', 'id');

Comment: Please try this before passing it to the other function: $newArray = array_map("intval", $places);

Answer (score 0):

To switch to the new driver (on Ubuntu):

Remove the old driver:
`apt-get remove php5-mysql`

Install the new driver:
`apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`

Restart apache2:
`service apache2 restart`